3.3 Theorem of Hamilton's The Ricci flow on surfaces
First picture below is from Hamilton's The Ricci flow on surfaces  (  237- 262  of this). Near the red line, why $R_{\max}$  can be replaced by $-\varepsilon$ ? In my view, only at start we know $R\le -\varepsilon$.
The $R$ is scalar curvature. Under normalized Ricci flow, it satisfy
$$
\partial_t R =\Delta R + R^2-rR
$$
where $r$ is the average of $R$, which is a constant under normalized Ricci flow.
In fact, I use the weak maximum principle  for scalars (the second picture) to get
$$
r-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{r}-(\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{\varepsilon})e^{rt}}\le r-R
$$
which is not same with 3.3 Theorem.







First, I should use maximum principle for scalar to prove "it remains so" of 3.3 Theorem. Hamilton omit it, and my English is so so.  Therefore, I get stuck.
